# Could microsoft remote desktop connection be used to spy?

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, privacy

I found a Program called Microsoft remote desktop connection on my mac but did not install it myself. Could somebody have been using it to spy on my computer use without my knowledge?
Would I be able to tell if my computer was being remotely accessed through that program while i was using my computer?

Comment: Have any of these answers been helpful?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure it can get installed as part of Office, as well as separately.

One app not to worry about, in fact - as it can only be used to 'dial out' to a Windows machine, not another Mac.

Answer (score 1):

No - that program lets your computer reach out and "spy" on other computers.

Unless your system has malware (which gladly we are starting to learn about thanks to some brave whistleblowers) - you can control your Mac's security in the Sharing Preference pane.

When you want your Mac to be remotely observable, choose screen sharing or remote management and turn them on. You can ask the system to tell you the status of remote management, but it's really up to the viewer to do the right thing as they can disable that notification in most instances if desired.

Comment: To say "that program lets your computer reach out and spy on other computers" is not a totally true statement and is quite misleading since the other computer User is usually aware an RDP connection has been established any typically by several indicators, it is not so stealth as to classify it a spying!

Comment: @user3439894 I didn't say it was a good spy or a stealthy one :-) Also, a great proportion of people are quite unaware of remote status and also do things even when they know they are being watched. If only a camera deterred all crime in our society.

Comment: I think you're your missing my point and the point of the OP. Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection is not intended to be Spyware, it's a legitimate application and has very positive uses.  Yes, it could be used in a subversive way however that is not the intent of the program.  Additionally unless it already setup not to show any indication it's running and a connection is established prior to a user sitting down at that computer I doubt it would go unnoticed.

Comment: RDC actually logs out the local user, so it would be pretty darn obvious anyway ;-)

Comment: @user3439894 I've put spy in quotes so everyone can focus on the direction of data flow - which is important - versus a pedantic take on the vocabulary the OP chose to use and my decision to use their term loosely. I'd encourage you to post an answer debunking all spying with that tool if it floats your boat :-)

Comment: The OP was worried abut their Mac being spied on by MRDC and since it can't be used in that context on a Mac, sans running Windows on a Mac via Boot Camp or in a VM, it is totally irrelevant in light of the fact that when making a connection via MRDC to a PC, or an occurrence of Windows running on a Mac, the Windows User is logged out and is a totally obvious event.  There is no need for me to post an answer "_debunking all spying_" especially since it's totally irrelevant to the context of the OP.  BTW I **was not** the down vote on your answer, even though I agree with it being down voted.

Comment: @user3439894 I take down votes as good feedback. I'm so happy for feedback, the -2 means nothing. I much prefer to know when I'm wrong, when what I writing is perceived as wrong. Even -10 on a post means people care. Same with comments - really sincere thanks.